# Using a single Flutter model for both isar database and JsonSerializable

Tags: flutter, model, retrofit, json-serializable, flutter-isar

I am trying to use a single model for both storing the data locally using Isar, and also for using with Retrofit for REST API requests.

But **Isar** requires all the Linked classes to be defined with the datatype `IsarLink<MyClassName>` where **JsonSerializable** requires them with `MyClassName` as the datatype.

```
@Collection()
@JsonSerializable()
class UserGroup {
  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  Id localId = Isar.autoIncrement; // you can also use id = null to auto increment

  @ignore
  @JsonKey(name: "_id")
  String? id;

  String name;
  String description;

  @ignore
  Domain? domain;
  
  @ignore
  UserGroupPermissions permissions;

  @ignore
  Organization? organization;

  
  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  IsarLink<Organization?> organization = IsarLink<Organization?>();

  UserGroup({
    this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    this.domain,
    required this.permissions,
    this.organization,
  });

  factory UserGroup.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserGroupFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserGroupToJson(this);
}
```

Other than defining two variables like `IsarLink<MyClassName> localOrganization` with `@JsonKey(ignore: true)` for **Isar** and `MyClassName` with `@ignore` for **JsonSerializable** is there any other way to use a single variable for working with both of them?

Having to define two variables almost everywhere to support both of the generators makes the code look really messy

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own `JsonConverter` to convert `IsarLink<Organization?>` to `Map<String, dynamic>` and vice versa